Using style.textAlign does not work when DIV class contains "display" declaration
Using the following, clicking the "Try Me" button aligns the DIV contents to the right:


function myFunction() {
    const divs = document.getElementsByClassName("outer_div");
    for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        let loop_div = divs.item(i);
        loop_div.style.textAlign = "right";
    }
}
.outer_div {
    margin:0px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
<div class="outer_div" style="background: white;">
  Test One
</div>
<div class="outer_div" style="background: white;">
  Test Two
</div>
<div class="outer_div" style="background: white;">
  Test Three
</div>

<hr>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>



The issue I'd like to fix is that if the CSS for the outer_div contains this:
display: flex;

That stops the right-align functionality of the button from working.
Example here:


function myFunction() {
    const divs = document.getElementsByClassName("outer_div");
    for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        let loop_div = divs.item(i);
        loop_div.style.textAlign = "right";
    }
}
.outer_div {
    margin:0px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
<div class="outer_div" style="background: white;">
  Test One
</div>
<div class="outer_div" style="background: white;">
  Test Two
</div>
<div class="outer_div" style="background: white;">
  Test Three
</div>

<hr>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>



Is there any way round that?
Sorry for all of the rules I have probably broken by asking this question.
Thanks

You need to use justify-content
For example:


function myFunction() {
    const divs = document.getElementsByClassName("outer_div");
    for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        let loop_div = divs.item(i);
        loop_div.style.justifyContent = "flex-end";
    }
}
.outer_div {
    margin:0px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
<div class="outer_div" style="background: white;">
  Test One
</div>
<div class="outer_div" style="background: white;">
  Test Two
</div>
<div class="outer_div" style="background: white;">
  Test Three
</div>

<hr>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>




Thank you Danny! That fixed it. I like your website by the way. Very cool!
